# Mysql if 'where' Clause condition failed then print php "message" else update row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql `'udate'` query with `'where'` condition checks `'$mobile'` with table 
    `column_field 'Mobile'`, if the value from `'textfield'`  to the `'where'` 
    condition is not matching with table column_field (Then the updation will 
    not occur on table row).
    If the 'where' condition does NOT match on the table column_field 
    `'Mobile'='$mobile'` , how can i print "Error Message" on php code.

```
<?php

$sql ="update mytable set total_amount = total_amount + '$total_amt',  
remaning_points = earned_points - redeemed_points where Mobile = '$mobile'";
$result = query($sql);
if (!$result) 
{
    echo "USER NOT EXISTING";
    exit;
}
else 
{
  echo "UPDATED";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can put your message in session and redirect to that particular page. `echo` your session variable and unset below that.

Comment: query is user defined function ?

Comment: Please show us the `query()` function. This is not vanilla PHP code so we have no idea what `query()` does or which PHP database API you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it as per answers or comments here, but the ideal way to do such things is to check for existence of the record, before you perform insert/update anything in database.

```
$query = 'select * from table where mobile="' . $mobile . '"';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   $query = 'update mytable set total_amount = total_amount + ' . $total_amt . ',  
remaning_points = earned_points - redeemed_points where Mobile = "' . $mobile . '"';
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
} 
else {
   echo "No record matched";
}
```

You can send this message to the other page by using `Session` or `GET`. This will your code will ensure `ACID` properties of Database. It should perform the check before performing Data Manipulation Language (DML) Statements.

Comment: Assuming of course that the OP is using the `mysqli_` API

Comment: of course, You can either of the API available, until and unless it perform the check before performing Data Manipulation Language (DML) Statements.

Comment: Missing  `concatenation operator`   near `$total_amt`

Comment: `SELECT *` just to see if there is a row with that key is rather a bad/wasteful way of checking for existance.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Agreed, I have demonstrated the way, you can use `EXISTS` operator as well. :D

Comment: @JYoThI, It's just for a demonstration purpose only. :P Still I will update.

Comment: Inside the single quotes everything consider as string even variable too

Comment: **Not fixed!** `$variables` are not expanded inside a single quoted string literal, that only works inside a double quoted string literal

Comment: It would also be safer to assume that the column `mobile` is not a numeric and therefore would require the value placing in quotes like `'$mobile'`

Comment: `+` plus is not `php` concatenation `operator` .it's `javascript` concatenation `operator`.

Comment: @JYoThI, Agreed, I am just trying to make a point of correct and better of doing it, not suggesting syntax or copy-paste ready code. :P

Comment: if your writing code i't should be write in right way . don't mix different language operator with it .

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen the mysql function [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)?

It returns how many rows/entrys were affected by your update query. If this functions returns zero (0) then it "failed" (the user does not exist).